# How to make jQuery intellisense work in VisualStudio Code for js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am working in VS Code on HTML and JS pages **(not a project)**.

I want jQuery intellisense to work in the js file.

When I write jQuery script in HTML in `<script>`

**The autocomplete and intellisense** is working, but when I try to write in external file js is not showing up.

I have tried to insert `jsconfig.json` in my folder by adding the below code

```
{
"typeAcquisition": {
    "include": [
        "jquery"
    ]
}}
```

It didn't work.

can anyone help?

Comment: Did you install the `jquery type definitions`? See here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery and more info here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript - PS I have no personal experience with this, and I don't know if this applies to the way you are editing your files.

Comment: Yes I have installed @PeterB but I am not using npm I am writing individual pages

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have found a solution to vscode specific:
`/// <reference path="path/to/jquery" />`  this line can be added to the external js file to get intellisence from the editor but it didn't function with other editors like sublime text.